# update a variable value and restart the activity again

Tags: android, variables, button, android-activity

iam creating an app where an activity has four buttons `button_total = 4`,  two in a row `button_row = 2`
what iam trying to achieve is when the user clicks the fourth button, the buttons should become as nine in total, three in a row.

i have created the variables `button_row` and `button_total` and incremented in the button`onclick` `case 4` code as follows :

```
button_row = button_row + 1;
button_total = (button_row * button_row);
```

now, that i have incremented the variables, HOW TO restart the activity with the updated varables, so that if the user clicks the 4th button the activity should show 9 buttons, 3 in a row..?

Comment: You do not need to restart the activity. You can just update the UI directly.

Comment: p.s. You should learn more about what `static` means. The way you use `static` here is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create a private method which updates the UI according to the values of these variables. Then you can call this method from `onCreate()` and anywhere else that you need to recreate the UI. This makes it so you do not have to restart the activity.

Comment: @amit Which part do you need clarified?

Comment: i am a bit confused that in the first screen there are four buttons and i have incremented the button_total value in the `onclick` of the fourth button, in the next screen (say updated screen) i want the button total value  to be incremented on the `onclick` of the ninth button, but the *second screen* will also have the *fourth button* with the increment code(as i have set it as case 1.. case 2..)

Comment: ...and also how to reference the variables of ShuffleButtons class in the private method you suggested to create?

Comment: @amit I am unclear what you mean by "updated screen" and and "second screen". What is the **first** screen?

Comment: @amit The private method that I suggested would go in ShuffleButtons, from what I understand of what you are doing. Then it can access all fields in ShuffleButtons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144968/discussion-between-amit-and-code-apprentice).